# Como fazer uma interface gráfica de um menu?

Tags: interface, gui, user-interface

Galera eu quero fazer um menu com interface gráfica, já fiz em C o código sem interface gráfica, mas como em C não é possível fazer interfaces, você sabem opções além de tkinter, qtcreator, visual studio, wxwindgets, por que o que tenho conhecimento é apenas python básico e C básico.

Bem isso é uma atividade proposta pelo meu professor e quero fazer, mas até agora não tenho a luz no fim do túnel com aulas que precisam de C++ e tenho pouco tempo.
Tava tentando em python mas não acho que vai atender ao que quero, um menu, vocês tem dicas por onde fazer e como fazer? Ou estudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Em C é possível fazer interfaces graficas sim!**

Você tem que ter o cabeçalho `windows.h` para acessar a API do windows.

```c
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;


    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Falha no registro!", "Erro!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }


    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "Janela em C.",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Falha na criação da janela!", "Erro!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);


    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: No caso eu estudo o que? Api, a pasta windows.h ou um geral c com interface gráfica?

Comment: Estude a  API. O windows.h reflete fielmente a API.